# Using React router , not able to go from /inida to /us and vice-versa. Other functionalities are working fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Not able to go from /India to /us and vice-versa. Other functionalities are working fine

Here is the code for App.js:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import Navbar from './Components.js/Navbar'
import News from "./Components.js/News";
import { Route, Routes, Navigate} from "react-router-dom";


export default function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar/>

            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Navigate to="/india" replace={true} />}/>
                <Route exact path="/india" element={<News key="general" category="general" country="in"/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/india/entertainment" element={<News key="entertainment" category="entertainment" country="in"/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/india/sports" element={<News key="sports" category="sports" country="in"/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/india/business" element={<News key="business" category="business" country="in"/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/india/health" element={<News key="health" category="health" country="in"/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/india/science" element={<News key="science" category="science" country="in"/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/india/technology" element={<News key="technology" category="technology" country="in"/>}/>

                <Route exact path="/us" element={<News key="general" category="general" country="us"/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/us/entertainment" element={<News key="entertainment" category="entertainment" country="us"/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/us/sports" element={<News key="sports" category="sports" country="us"/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/us/business" element={<News key="business" category="business" country="us"/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/us/health" element={<News key="health" category="health" country="us"/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/us/science" element={<News key="science" category="science" country="us"/>}/>
                <Route exact path="/us/technology" element={<News key="technology" category="technology" country="us"/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </>
    )
}
```

Here is my NavBar.js:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { Route, Routes, useLocation, useNavigate ,Redirect, Navigate} from "react-router-dom";
import { NavLink,Link } from "react-router-dom";
 
const Navbar=()=>{
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [cat,set_cat]=useState("");
    const [country,set_country]=useState("india");
    return (
        <>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <a className="navbar-brand" to="#">Navbar</a>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                            <li className="nav-item" onClick={()=>set_cat("")}>
                                <NavLink className="nav-link" to={`/${country}`}>HOME</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            {/* <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link" to="/about">About</a></li> */}
                            <li className="nav-item" onClick={()=>set_cat("business")}><NavLink className="nav-link" to={`/${country}/business`}>BUSINESS</NavLink></li>
                            <li className="nav-item" onClick={()=>set_cat("entertainment")}><NavLink className="nav-link" to={`/${country}/entertainment`}>ENTERTAINMENT</NavLink></li>
                            <li className="nav-item" onClick={()=>set_cat("health")}><NavLink className="nav-link" to={`/${country}/health`}>HEALTH</NavLink></li>
                            <li className="nav-item" onClick={()=>set_cat("science")}><NavLink className="nav-link" to={`/${country}/science`}>SCIENCE</NavLink></li>
                            <li className="nav-item" onClick={()=>set_cat("sports")}><NavLink className="nav-link" to={`/${country}/sports`}>SPORTS</NavLink></li>
                            <li className="nav-item" onClick={()=>set_cat("technology")}><NavLink className="nav-link" to={`/${country}/technology`}>TECHNOLOGY</NavLink></li>

                            <li className="nav-item" onClick={()=>{navigate('/india'); set_country("india"); }}><Link className="nav-link" to={`/india`}>India</Link></li>
                            <li className="nav-item" onClick={()=>{navigate('/us'); set_country("us"); }}><Link className="nav-link" to={`/us`}>US</Link></li>
                           
                        </ul>
                        <form className="d-flex" role="search">
                            <input className="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
                                <button className="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

We can successfully navigate from any link to any other but when trying to navigate to /us to /India or /India to /us the data is not updating on the page.

I tried everything such as created onclick, tried forceupdate but could not fix the issue.

Comment: You might also try unique keys between the routes, e.g. `key="general-india"` versus `key="general-us"`, etc.